# Is returning a dereferenced iterator the same as an object?

Tags: c++

I am trying to return an object of type `Vertex` from a vector. I can only use the iterator; does returning a dereferenced iterator do what I want? To be more precise I want initialize `v2` to a pointer of the `Vertex` I am returning: that is:

```
Vertex* v2;
v2 = &(p_graph->getVertex(vert2));
```

In order to do that I have to use `getVertex()` that returns a `Vertex` to I prepend it with & to make a pointer and assign it to `v2`.  The `getVertex()` function is:

```
Vertex Graph::getVertex(std::string v) {         // gets the vertex 
    for (std::vector<Vertex>::iterator it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); it++) {
        if ((it->getName()).compare(v) == 0)
            return *it;  // if strings are the same return vertex
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

But I am not able to assign it so there is an error somewhere in this part of the code that I have been trying to find for a couple of hours.

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Two things: (1) in C++ you can use `==` to compare things, so you can simply do `if (it->getName() == v)`; (2) I'd recommend using an `assert` instead of `exit(1)`.

Comment: @Mahesh The message is "Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector
Line: 240

Expression: vector iterators incompatible"

Comment: Thanks. Did the solution I suggested worked ? Most probably, I think that is the problem.

Comment: Change your `getVertex()` function to return a reference (`Vertex&`).

Comment: For the love of all thats good, please use <shared_ptr>. I hate naked pts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to take the address of a temporary.

```
(p_graph->getVertex(vert2));
```

The expression `(p_graph->getVertex(vert2))` returns a temporary and the life time of such temporary is until `;` is reached.

The scenario is more like -

```
Vertex *v2 = & Vertex();
```

You have an option of `const` qualifying the `v2` which extends life time of such temporary. Try -

```
const Vertex* v2 = &(p_graph->getVertex(vert2));
```

Comment: Why about not use Vertex * on stack at all?

Comment: @Mahesh I went through with a debugger and I am getting the error on line  "p_graph->addVertex(*v2);  // add vertex2 to the graph" but I still don't know why?

Comment: Can you post what you are doing in `addVertex` ?

Comment: @Mahesh When I tried the above const approach I got: 'Vertex::addEdge' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Vertex' to 'Vertex &'

Comment: @Mahesh The vertex version    void addVertex(Vertex* vert) { connPtrVertices.push_back(vert); }     The graph version   void Graph::addVertex(const Vertex v) {
    vertices.push_back(v);
}

Comment: See that is the problem. Earlier, you have binded a temporary to `v2`. When you dereferenced it later (`p_graph->addVertex(*v2);`, it crashed.

Comment: Now, the new issue is that a const type can not call non-const member functions.

Comment: @Mahesh how would you fix it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36630/discussion-between-mahesh-and-napalidon)

Comment: @Mahesh so I should remove const form addVertex(const Vertex v)? But what about the l-value problem, any way to fix that?

Comment: @Napalidon: A temporary is a value created as the result of an expression. Temporary values only exist until the end of the statement where they were created. To preserve a temporary, you must store it into a variable (which actually makes a copy of the temporary, although in C++11 it can result in just moving the temporary). To see why some operations are illegal on temporaries, consider the result of `&(x+y)`. That intermediate result has no permanent address to refer to.

Comment: +1 the `Vertex * p = &(Vertex())` is a very good simplification of the problem at hand. I'd likely have `getVertex()` return a reference or a const-reference and store the results in a ref wrapper (as I understand it he's keeping his current pointers in a separate container, a vector of `Vertex*` I believe). But regardless, your analysis of the problem is spot-on.